# SQL Query to select where other rows do not equal values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT arg2 as r 
FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
WHERE queuename = '0536*401'
      AND time > '2014-04-02 10:30:00'
      AND event = 'CONNECT'
```

but also where other rows with the same `callid` (column name) do not have an event of `CONNECT` or `ABANDON` or `RINGNOANSWER`

For example, I have these rows:

```
callid  queuename    time                 event          arg2
1234    0536*401    2014-04-02 10:30:00   ENTERQUEUE     0192837465
1234    0536*401    2014-04-02 10:30:00   CONNECT
1234    0536*401    2014-04-02 10:30:00   RINGNOANSWER
```

So, because the rows with events `CONNECT` and `RINGNOANSWER` are there with the same `callid`, `arg2` should not display, however if the second two rows do not exist it will show `arg2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join the table to itself. try:

```
SELECT arg2 as r FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log v1
    WHERE queuename = '0536*401'
    AND time > '2014-04-02 10:30:00'
    AND event = 'CONNECT'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log v2
                    WHERE v1.CallID = v2.CallID
                    AND v2.event in ('CONNECT','ABANDON ','RINGNOANSWER')
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the readable version of your query:

```
SELECT arg2 as r 
FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log 
WHERE queuename = '0536*401'
      AND time > '2014-04-02 10:30:00'
      AND callid NOT IN ( select callid 
                          from voipwallboard_ast_queue_log
                          where event not in ( 'CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 
                                               'RINGNOANSWER' )
                         )
```

But performance will not be the best because it check subquery for each row.

To improve performance you should left join table with itself:

```
SELECT l.arg2 as r 
FROM voipwallboard_ast_queue_log l left outer join
    ( select callid 
                          from voipwallboard_ast_queue_log
                          where event not in ( 'CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 
                                               'RINGNOANSWER' )
                         )  T
       on l.callid = T.callid
WHERE l.queuename = '0536*401'
      AND l.time > '2014-04-02 10:30:00'
      AND t.callid is null
```